# This link no longer works/where do I go to get a developer key? http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/

Tags: youtube, key

Hi: I've tried going to this link, http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/dashboard/, which is listed as the url for a product YouTube developer key. I've tried it on 3 computers, 3 different browsers, and I keep getting Error 502. Have been trying for several hours now. Can you please point me in the right direction? Thank you.